# Pandas function to add field to dataframe does not work

Tags: python, dataframe, function

I have some code which I want to use in a dynamic python function. This code adds a field to an existing dataframe and does some adjustments to it. However, I got the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers". What am I doing incorrectly?

See below the function plus the code for calling the function.

```
import pandas as pd

#function
def create_new_date_column_in_df_based_on_other_date_string_column(df,df_field_existing_str,df_field_new):
    df[df_field_new] = df[df_field_existing_str]
    df[df_field_new] = df[df_field_existing_str].str.replace('12:00:00 AM','')
    df[df_field_new] = df[df_field_existing_str].str.strip()
    df[df_field_new]=pd.to_datetime(df[df_field_existing_str]).dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    return df[df_field_new]

#calling the function
create_new_date_column_in_df_based_on_other_date_string_column(df='my_df1',df_field_existing_str='existingfieldname',df_field_new='newfieldname')
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters `df` you are giving the function is of type `str`, and so is `df_field_existing_str`.

What basically you're doing is trying to slice a string/get a specific characters by using the `[]` (or the `.__getitem__()` method) with another string which is impossible.

You are not using a DataFrame here, only strings, thus you are getting this `TypeError`.